# How to get all enable and disable products from a specific category?

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

i am trying to get all enabled and disabled products and i am using this code :

```
/*$categoryId = 3; // a category id that you can get from admin
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                   ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('gt' => 0))
                    ->load();

$categoryId = 3; // a category id that you can get from admin
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);*/
```

above code brings enabled products only.

By commenting status filter it still brings the same result i.e. only enabled products.

```
    /*$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()
                   ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    //->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('gt' => 0))
                    ->load();*/
```

It still brings only Enabled products. **But when i comment category check than it brings n all products** :( Can anyone help plz ?

**Note:**

For those who are not clear about this query, let me tell you that **Status Enabled = 1** and **Status Disabled = 2**.

So status greater than zero should bring me both enabled and disabled products, but it is not doing so.
So any idea ???

I Edit the code and it

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)
                    ->getProductCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                    ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'ASC');

die((string) $collection->getSelect());
```

And this bring in this query :

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id='3' ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id` ASC
```

Comment: maybe you should start to at least read what you copy/paste ..

Comment: @Ovidiu ! i suggest you should explain what you perceive. i guess you are wrong somewhere.

Comment: ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('gt' => 0)) it's pretty self explanatory. Simply remove it from your collection filter and you will have products no matter what status they have. Since there are only two statuses and you want to get products with both status enable and disable.

Comment: @Ovidiu even if you comment this line, still you get all enabled products only,
whereas, i want DISABLED PRODUCTS also

Comment: Try doing a `die((string) $collection->getSelect());` to see what query it actually builds. It might be changing the status clause somewhere and you wouldn't know.

Comment: @clockworkgeek ! see the change code and query it builds, and see if there is any issue specific to version 1.6.2 cummunity edition.

Comment: When I try your code it works perfectly. Something else is modifying your collection after-the-fact, something that you haven't shown here such as a third party module.

Comment: @clockworkgeek ! i am doing this operation in helper class of a my custom module, is this something that can affect ???

Comment: I was thinking the cause must be hard to spot, like an event observer from another module, or a cached response being returned instead.

Answer (score 8):

I have found why is this happening.

This is because when you want to get products from category using `$productCollection->addCategoryFilter()` or using `$category->getProductCollection()` query use product to category connection INDEX table. When you run re-index that product category connection INDEX table is populated only with Enabled products, and you can not get disabled products on that way. Is this bug in Magento or not I do not know, you can use Raw SQL query to get your products from a specific category.

Answer (score 3):

You use `->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('gt' => 0))` on your collection, that filters on enabled products, so you can remove this line to get all products

Comment: ! hope you are well aware of the fact that Status Enabled = 1 and status disabled = 2

Comment: Forgot about it as it's not really natural, but you can then use instead `->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)`

Comment: ! as i mentioned i need to withdraw all enabled and disabled products :(
the code you pasted above will bring me just enabled products.

Answer (score 3):

Using your example, with minor change to reflect my category ID.

In category 233 I have 44 products, all enabled.

```
    $categoryId = 233; // a category id that you can get from admin

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
//  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('gt' => 0)) //filter commented, show all products
    ->load();

echo $collection->count(); // 44 products


$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 1)) //show only enabled
    ->load();

echo $collection->count(); // 44 products

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => 2)) //only disabled 
    ->load();

echo $collection->count(); // 0 products
```

As I said in my comment, I don't understand why do you want to filter status if  you want to get both possible statuses.

Comment: ! thanks for the reply, but what i am trying to communicate is that even if you comment this line, still it is not showing disable products.
i want ENABLED and DISABLED both products. But right now i am not able to get the disabled products.

Comment: Something else must be wrong. I just tested this. Disabled a product from that category and I still get 44 count without the status filter.

Comment: But as a workaround, you can get two colections and merge. One with disabled and one with enabled.

Comment: Ovidiu ! I tested the same code and it is giving me count = 7, whereas totall products are 9 in which 2 are disabled.
But when i comment category filter line, then all works fine like a magic

Comment: Then check your category (3) and see how many products you have in it. From what you say seems that you have 9 total products in magento but only 7 in that category.

Comment: nopx, 9 products have been assigned to this specific category :( double checked

Comment: Its probably not working as expected for Ovidiu as he is most likely not rebuilding his catalogue product index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Magento's constant  `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED` will only return the products that are disabled within a category

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
->getProductCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'status',
    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED)
);
```

Comment: Using Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED is a much more refined way of doing this.